I am not able to do OTP authentication(receiving OTP using phone number) for my flutter project after publishing the bundle on Play Store
This is a follow up question for Google Play Store rejecting updated flutter app bundle because off adding SMS and Call Log Permissions.
But I am facing the same issue back again. I just can not use my OTP function(for user authentication) after installing the app on a physical device. There were no issues while testing the app on the emulator.
Note: I have built the OTP authentication using Twilio and Django. Calling the APIs on my flutter code. Not using firebase/supabase.
I uploaded the version 1 app bundle. Was suggested to use the SMS retriever API for the problem earlier. So I installed the SMS autofill package:
dependencies:
  sms_autofill: ^2.4.0

After this I was assuming that the problem would be solved but no output. Whenever I enter a phone number, I get no response. This was working fine while running on the android emulator, but not on a physical device.
